# Calling a class function from within another class function - JS newb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

This is probably more of a javascript question but I dont really know javascript in general, so im hoping its a simple fix.

So basically I am using two libraries that I want to work together. The beacon class listens for a bluetooth LE signal on a raspberry pi, at which point the onAdvertisement fucntion is called from the node-beacon-scanner library.

When this happens I want to publish a message to a message broker using MQTT (the other library), which should be a case of just calling client.publish(topic, message).

THe publish function works when I use it outside of the scanner functions, however if I call it inside one of the scanner functions such as onAdvertisement, it doesnt work, but also doesnt throw any errors.

I think it is an issue of me not understanding encapsualtion in node.js regarding modules.

Basically I want to know is there somthign im missing when calling the client.publish function from within the scanner.onadvertisement function? In the code below the publish call has been put in a function called pubBe.

Thankyou in advance!

```
    const noble = require('@abandonware/noble');
    const BeaconScanner = require("node-beacon-scanner");
    const mqtt = require('mqtt');
    
    var client  = mqtt.connect('http://localhost:1883');
    var scanner = new BeaconScanner();
    var ledOn = false
    
    client.on('connect', function () {
      client.subscribe('led', function (err) {
        if (!err) {
          
        }
      })
    })
     
    client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
      // message is Buffer
      console.log(message.toString())
      client.end()
    })
    
    scanner.onadvertisement = (advertisement) => {
        var beacon = advertisement["rssi"]
    }
    
    scanner.startScan().then(() => {
        console.log("Scanning has started...")
        pubBe(-10)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    })
    
    function pubBe(rssi){
      if( rssi > -40 && !ledOn){
        console.log('Turn LED on')
        ledOn = true
        payload = {"level": 100}
        client.publish('led', JSON.stringify(payload))
        
      }else if ( rssi < -40 && ledOn){
        console.log('Turn LED off')
        ledOn = false
        payload = {"level": 0}
        client.publish('led', JSON.stringify(payload))      
      }        
    }
```

Comment: Where is the payload variable being declared?

Comment: Is the client able to subscribe the led? You are not handling the case if subscribing the led failed. So maybe that didn't work, therefore publishing to the led would has no effect.